# Why is auto on grid-template-columns making multiple elements the same width?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, width, auto

**What i'm trying to make**
A list of items (not a ul/ol kind of list) is placed in the center of a page, these items have 2 columns. The first column should have a "fixed" width (`1em` in this case), and the second column should be as width as it's title (i tried to do this with `auto`).

**The issue**
All items get the same width as the longest item. In the example below i gave the `.item` and `.something-else` items a border to make it more visual.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem; 
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1em auto;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.something-else {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">1</div>
      <div class="something-else">Some title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">2</div>
      <div class="something-else">This is a longer title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">3</div>
      <div class="something-else">Another one</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What i tried**

- Using flex for the `.item` elements. This does make the `.something-else` do what i want, but all the `.item` elements are still the same width ([See here for the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/z7khouwb/))
- Tried playing around with inline-grid
- Using flex/inline-flex on the `.wrapper` as well
- Adding a container with `flexbox` around all the items

I feel normally i get these kind of things pretty easy to work, although i might not really know what is happening. This time no luck tho.

Would also appreciate if someone can explain why this is not working, and if they have an answer also have some explanation with it.

I'm ok with a solution using `flexbox`, but prefer `grid` (i want to understand it better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the stretch alignment by using `margin-right: auto` or justify-self: start or `justify-items: start` on the container:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem; 
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1em auto;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-right: auto; /* ADDED */
  /* OR justify-self: start*/
}

.something-else {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">1</div>
      <div class="something-else">Some title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">2</div>
      <div class="something-else">This is a longer title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="something">3</div>
      <div class="something-else">Another one</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani. Is it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout i should read up about to know more about why/how this is happening? Or?